# Label vertices of classic graph

Tags: tkz-berge

I want to add the Chvatal graph but use my own labels to label the vertices of the graph 3 different ways. Since it's a classic graph, the edges are given for free. I'd rather modify the classic graph than start over and have to build the edges as well. By following the [documentation](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge/doc/tkz-berge-screen.pdf), I have the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\SetVertexNoLabel
\SetGraphShadeColor{black}{blue}{gray}
\grChvatal[RA=7,RB=3]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can tell, the vertices won't be labeled. I only plan to use 1, 2, 3, 4, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h as labels, so there should be enough room to place them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `\AssignVertexLabel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\SetVertexNoLabel
\SetGraphShadeColor{black}{blue}{gray}
\grChvatal[RA=7,RB=3]
\AssignVertexLabel[color=white]{a}{1,2,3,4}
\AssignVertexLabel[color=white]{b}{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```